# use multiple conditions in 'test' command

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to convert the following code to use 'test' instead of 'if'

```
if [ -e ./blah ] &&  [ ! -L ./blah ];
then
   exit 1
fi
```

My intention is to use test instead, so that I dont have to exit 1 explicitly. I am trying something like this:

```
test -e ./blah  && ! -L ./blah;
```

instead of &&, I have tried -a, with different bracket combinations, but I am not successful. I am sure there should be a simple way to do this. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`test` does not understand logical operators `&&` and `||`. You can use `test -e ./blah -a ! -L ./blah`, but if you are using bash, you can also switch to its more powerful `[[ .. ]]` construct:

```
[[ -e ./blah && ! -L ./blah ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

To make `if [ -e ./blah ] &&  [ ! -L ./blah ];` work, use the following
`if [ -e ./blah -a ! -L ./blah ];`  (`-a` stands for `and`) http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Demo -- http://ideone.com/GR8UiK

But, as others have pointed out, `[[ .. ]]` construct is more powerful than `[...]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ -e ./blah ] && [ ! -L ./blah ];
```

is equivalent to

```
if test -e ./blah && test ! -L ./blah;
```

Therefore you can simply write

```
test -e ./blah && test ! -L ./blah
```

To wit:

```
$ help [\[] | tail -n +3
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them all (including if then fi):

```
[[ -e ./blah && ! -L ./blah ]] && exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[` keyword as it is more powerful.

```
if [[ -e ./blah && ! -L ./blah ]]
    then
    ...
fi
```

However, to ensure portability, you can do something like this too

```
if [ -e ./blah ] && [ ! -L ./blah  ] 
    then
    ...do something
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

As you ask to use `test`, you can do like so:

```
test -e ./blah && test -L ./blah || ( echo 'First action' ; echo 'Second action )
```

The different operators (`&&`, `||`, etc...) are first parsed by the shell, so you can't use it in command parameter(s).

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
$ ls -i /bin/test
54008404 /bin/test
$ ls -i /bin/[
54008404 /bin/test
```

That `54008404` is the *inode* number. This is the real name of a file. The `/bin/test` simply points to the `inode` and the `inode` contains all file file information.

The thing to note is that `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` are the same *inode*. That means, they're the same command.

Thus:

```
if [ -f "$foo" ]
```

is the same as:

```
if test -f "$foo"
```

The `if` command executes the command given, and then will execute the `if` clause if the command returns true and doesn't execute the clause if the command it false.

For example:

```
if grep -q "foo" $foo
then
    echo "File $foo contains the regular expression /foo/"
fi
```

Is completely valid. The `grep -q` command (in many variants of `grep` means search for the regular expression, and if that regular expression is in the file, return an exit code of `0` (which means the command succeeded and is true).

Note there is no square brackets.

The `test` command (or `[...]`) merely runs a test as specified, and returns with an exit code of `0` (thus the command is a success) if the test is true. That's all it does.

You may also see this construct:

```
[ "$foo" = "$bar" ] && echo "$foo is equal to $bar"
```

The `&&` means execute the next command (and return the exit code) if the first command returns an exit code of zero. Otherwise, simply return the first command's exit code.

Thus:

```
if [ -e ./blah ] &&  [ ! -L ./blah ];
```

is saying run `test -e ./blah` and if that is true (that is, the file exists) execute `test ! -L ./blah` and if that is also true, run the `if` clause of the statement.

Note that `[ -e ./blah]` and `[ ! -L ./blah ]` are two separate commands. The `&&` strings together the two commands:

```
[ "$foo" = "$bar" ] && some_command;
```

This says, run `test "$foo" = "$bar"` and if that is true, run the command `some_command`. Note that this is equivalent to:

```
if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]
then
    some_command
fi
```

The other list structure is the `||`. This means that if the first command succeeds, return an exit code of `0` and don't run the second command. Thus:

```
[ "$foo" = "$bar" ] || some_command;
```

Is the same as:

```
if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]
then
    :
else
     some_command
fi
```

Let's get back to your _original question:

```
if [ -e ./blah ] &&  [ ! -L ./blah ];
then
   exit 1
fi
```

Is the same as:

```
if test -e ./blah && test ! -L ./blah
then
    exit 1
fi
```

Which is the same as

```
test -e ./blah && test ! -L ./blah && exit 1
```

This means: If `test -e ./blah` is true (./blah is a file), then execute the command after the `&&` list operator. This is `test -! -L ./blah`. If this test also is true, run the command after the `&&` list operator again.

This could also be rewritten as:

```
test -e ./blah && test -L ./blah || exit 1
```

This says that if `test -e ./blah` is true, run the command after the `&&` list operator. If `test -L ./blah` is false, run the command after the `||` operator.